# Hot Network Questions are HTTP links when the site itself is served via HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, ssl, hot-questions

Links to Hot Network Questions are always HTTP links, even when the site is accessed over HTTPS.

This is inconsistent with question links in Linked and Related sections (when Stack Overflow is accessed over HTTPS, the links in Linked and Related section are HTTPS links).

Comment: I think the official response would be: "HTTPS is not fully supported over SE network".

Comment: Stack Exchange does not really care about https.

Comment: Related request I posted earlier on meta.SE: [All internal links on Stack Exchange sites should be protocol-relative](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223725/all-internal-links-on-stack-exchange-sites-should-be-protocol-relative)

Comment: any word on whether SE's https priority will change with Chrome's latest plans? http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/09/08/chrome_to_shame_non_https_sites/

Comment: There's a [lot of work going on right now](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/776483602209079296) to support the move to SSL, though we may have to [wait a bit longer](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/775802579657846784) for the blog post about it.

Comment: @Dave I love how that article was published on a non-HTTPS site. :P